# How to open and save a file in an exe through python

Tags: python, subprocess

Essentially I want to open an application/executable file (which I can do). Then, through python, I wanted to tell the exe to open a file and then save it, all without interacting with the exe window directly.

Is this actually possible? I had been using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: This depends entirely on the specific executable file and what control mechanisms it was built to offer. Some operating systems might offer additional generic interfaces, but you haven't specified an operating system at all, and you'll need 3rd-party libraries to use those additional interfaces regardless, as the Python standard library generally sticks to portable functionality.

Comment: Provide more specific question. What executable?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am using windows, and it is a custom executable. Do you reckon it's impossible then?

Comment: Impossible unless you build your executable to cooperate (via some kind of RPC mechanism -- no shortage of choices) or use one of the many relevant libraries for the purpose external to Python itself. Which is to say not impossible at all.

Comment: See f/e https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto (this link added as a comment instead of an answer because library recommendations are off-topic).